# Entity Framework 4.0 insert new object error

Tags: .net, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I have a project using Entity Framework 4.0 in Visual Studio 2010. I have the following code:

```
using (var db = new MyEntities())
{
    var dbLead = db.Leads.CreateObject();
    dbLead.Email = lead.Email;
    db.Leads.AddObject(dbLead);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

where `MyEntities` is the usual EF object context. `Lead` is an EF-generated class, which maps to a corresponding table in the database. In addition to the `Email` property assigned in the code above, the `Lead` class has an `Id` property, which I am not explicitly setting here. All the expected stuff, nothing strange yet.

I'm getting an exception on the call to `db.SaveChanges()`, citing "duplicate primary key" as the problem. However, in the DB, I have the corresponding column marked as a primary key, and in the .edmx designer, the corresponding property is marked with EntityKey as true and StoreGeneratedPattern as Identity.

Couple questions:

1. Why isn't the designer smart enough to have StoreGeneratedPattern set to Identity by default when it generates the class, assuming the underlying table has the corresponding column set to a primary key? In my case, I had to go into every class in the designer, and set this value myself for every primary key property (though, interestingly, EntityKey is set to true by default, as expected).
2. It's still not working... Why? I've tried setting the StoreGeneratedPattern to Computed instead, but no luck (expected, otherwise I'd be wondering why setting it to Computed fixed the problem).

Comment: You use the default code generation template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the `IsIdentity` to `Yes` for the `Id` column in the Database. I assume that's the problem here, since you mention that EF itself doesn't set `StoreGeneratedPattern` to `Identity`.

Comment: In the database, I had the `Id` column marked with Primary Key. On your recommendation I looked a little deeper and noticed that the Identity Column property on the table itself was blank, so I set it to the `Id` column. I then removed the `Lead` class in the .edmx designer and ran an update from the DB. Lo and behold, it generated the `Lead` class with StoreGeneratedPattern set to Identity, and now it works. Is that what you meant by `IsIdentity`? Because I didn't see anything by that name.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant (just repeating the way it is in SQL Server Management Studio), sorry if I was unclear. In any case, the field was a `PK`, but not `Identity` in the DB, so EF tried to insert the same Id value (probably 0) over and over, and thus failed.

Comment: I didn't realize that having a field as `PK` meant something different from having it as the `Identity`, but now that's cleared up. Thanks!